# Comparing two values in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which I would like get all the names of
someone who's salary is less than then the next person in
the same table, I have tried this but 
its not working any suggestions?

```
select t1.Name, t2.Name as Name2 
from employees t1 
inner join employees t2 on 
t1.ID = t2.ID
where t1.Salary < t2.Salary;
```

I am trying to print out the names of each person that has a lesser salary then the next for example

```
Joe "has less then" Bob
Joe "has less then" foo
Joe "has less then" Bar
Joe "has less then" Pete
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a "next person" in a table, unless another column specifies the ordering.

Comment: You could try using two different MySQL queries then using PHP to compare the two; however, in each query you will probably have to define which employee your choosing. As @GordonLinoff said, "There is no such thing as a next person in a table".

Comment: @seus its bit strange the requirement, are you looking for salaries greater or lesser than some value? i'm not sure with why you are looking for person with salary less than next person.

Comment: I am trying to print out the names of each person that has a lesser salary then the next for example Joe "has less then" Bob

Comment: @seus, not sure if this is possible but have one query accessing each persons name/salary through a variable in the SQL query. Then have a loop to show names and salary of who has less than the original person.

Answer (score 1):

Compare your current and next id column

```
select t1.Name, t2.Name as Name2 ,t1.salary,t2.salary
from employees t1 
inner join employees t2 on 
t1.ID+1 = t2.Id
where t1.Salary < t2.Salary;
```

Comment: Thanks for this but Its not giving me my desired result

Comment: Please post your table structure and desired result

Comment: I added what results I am after in the question

Comment: @seus i have update my answer and its working.please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining on the same ID. You are comparing the salary of the same person.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t.LastName
from (
    select Name, 
    Salary, 
    @last_name AS LastName, 
    @last_sal AS LastSal, 
    @last_name := Name , 
    @last_sal := Salary 
    from employees
    cross join (select @last_name := NULL, @last_sal := NULL) param
    ) t
where t.LastSal < t.Salary;
```

Comment: There has to be a better way :(

Comment: I am looking forward too. Waiting for the ans

Comment: This method should return the expected result. do you have any other working way?

Answer (score 0):

`select t1.Name || " has less then " || t2.Name 
from employees t1, employees t2
where t1.Salary < t2.Salary;`

if you remove the inner join (resulting join will be a cross join) in that (I believe) you will be able to find what you are looking for.

PS: the query is not tested on any database schema, however it will work, m not sure on the concatenation syntax though.